# Javascript method is not returning a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little new to Javascript. I'm doing on a project for work and I'm having some trouble getting a method to return a percentage.

```
function campaignProgress(goal, current){
    this.goal = goal;
    this.current = current; 
    this.percent =  Math.floor(current / goal  * 100);

    this.getGoal = function(){
        return goal;
    }
    this.getCurrent = function(){
        return current;
    }
    this.getPercent = function(){   
        return percent;
    }
}


var totalProgress = new campaignProgress(1.70, 1.064);
```

When I call it in the html file I reference the .js file in my header and in the body I use;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.write(totalProgress.getGoal());

        document.write(totalProgress.getPercent());

</script>
```

The getGoal() method works fine but getPercent() returns nothing. I can reference the percent variable itself like this;

```
totalProgress.percent
```

and it'll print fine. Any advice on why this is not working would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: any console messages you are getting?

Comment: percent is undefined, you want this.percent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to mimic a class, where, those should be "private". I think you'd want:

```
function campaignProgress(goal, current){
    var privateGoal = goal,
        privateCurrent = current;

    this.getGoal = function(){
        return privateGoal;
    };
    this.setGoal = function(g){
        privateGoal = g;
    };
    this.getCurrent = function(){
        return privateCurrent;
    };
    this.setCurrent = function(c){
        privateCurrent = c;
    };
    this.getPercent = function(){   
        return Math.floor(privateCurrent / privateGoal  * 100);
    };
}

var tp = new campaignProgress(1.70, 1.064);
console.log(tp.getGoal(), tp.getCurrent(), tp.getPercent());
tp.setCurrent(1.111);
console.log(tp.getGoal(), tp.getCurrent(), tp.getPercent());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/twVNN/2/

This causes `privateGoal` and `privateCurrent`  to be "private", meaning they can't be accessed outside their scope. The methods provided allow that access by calling them instead. Using `this.goal = goal;` is unnecessary if you're going to use something like `getGoal`. The `privatePercent` dynamically calculates the percent based on the values of `privateCurrent` and `privateGoal`.

Comment: that breaks the named arguments.

Comment: @dandavis What are you talking about?

Comment: you should not re-declare (var ) a previously declared variable, in this case goal and current.

Comment: @dandavis Instead of arguing, I'll just change and accept your suggestion. It didn't hurt to have before, but it was unnecessary

Comment: it's just poor form, even if it worked, and there are some old browser fringe-case instances where the hoisting pattern can cause a problem when formals and lexical overlap.

Comment: @dandavis No you're right, I read the question/code too fast and realized that was dumb to do; and I provided a horrible explanation/example at first. It might've made sense if I used different variable names, but even then it was still unnecessary

Comment: @Ian would using this format be more ideal if I'm going to have more than one instance of campaignProgress in the same .js file. For example my plan is to have multiple variables like this;

    `code`var totalProgress = new campaignProgress(1.70, 1.064);
    
    `code`var alumniProgress = new campaignProgress(.0142, .0072);
    
    `code`var artsProgress = new campaignProgress(.03, .0058);

Sorry for the mess, this is my first post and I'm struggling with the markup formatting.

Comment: @WhyAyala I don't know if it's **more ideal** but it's how I would set it up. You could use your code (slightly modified/fixed) with multiple `campaignProgress` objects, there's nothing wrong with that, but note that you'd technically be able to do `alumniProgress.percent = "whatever";` and change that value. With my setup, the value of `goal` and `current` are "locked in" after invoking the object. You could always add setters (following traditional OOP)

Comment: @Ian edited answer is interesting, i didn't know that variables passed in are auto-declared (suppose this only applies to classes). Good to know, clean, but feels weird.

Comment: @Ian I had thought about setters too but my employer told me they're not necessary for our purposes.

Comment: @WhyAyala They're only necessary if you expect to want to change the value of the private variables at a later time (using my setup). If the value of `goal` and `current` won't change over time, you don't need the setters

Comment: @Ian The value of current is definitely going to change over time but my employer wants to just change the current variable in the .js file. Basically all the info that I'm storing in each variable that's an instance of campaignProgress is info that is hardcoded in HTML all over their site. They want all the info accessible in one file so if something needs to be changed they can find it in one location.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return through the scope of the instance `this`:

```
this.getGoal = function(){
    return this.goal;
}
this.getCurrent = function(){
    return this.current;
}
this.getPercent = function(){   
    return this.percent;
}
```

`goal` and `current` are returned because of closure with the constructor parameters. But if they are changed after the constructor runs then they would return wrong values. This is apparent with the `percent` variable.

Comment: @dandavis No, they are properties of the instance (`totalProgress`), not local variables.

Comment: @dandavis But then what if we want to access them through `this`?

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics That worked, thanks. Your explanation makes perfect sense looking at it now.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics I voted you down, not dandavis. Because this is unnecessary to do. And the value of `this` isn't guaranteed to be what you expect inside those functions anyways. I doubt this is what the OP (or anyone) wants. Why would you declare a "public" property, and then "public" methods just to get them?

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics: i've never voted anybody anything. look at my badges. i was talking about the OP's code where this.current is not needed...

Comment: @Ian The point you're making is actually irrelevant to the question. The user can experience this issue in valid scenarios where the method doesn't just return the properties but performs operations with them.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning your variables as properties of the function (`this.goal`), but when you retrieve them you are trying to get local variables. This should fix it:

```
function campaignProgress(goal, current){
    this.goal = goal;
    this.current = current; 
    this.percent =  Math.floor(current / goal  * 100);

    this.getGoal = function(){
        return this.goal;
    }
    this.getCurrent = function(){
        return this.current;
    }
    this.getPercent = function(){   
        return this.percent;
    }
}
```

The other question here is are you using `new` to create an instance of this "function class"? Otherwise assigning this.goal will be assigning those variables to global scope.

```
var c = campaignProgress(1, 3);
console.log(c);//undefined
console.log(window.goal);//1
```

vs

```
var c = new campaignProgress(1, 3)
console.log(c);//instance
console.log(window.goal);//undefined
```

Comment: Using this is preferable since they are being set as properties. This means they may be altered elsewhere. By just accessing the local vars they will remain unaware of changes to the properties.

Comment: since OP is using getters, it doesn't much matter.

Answer (score 2):

You nee to use closures `var that = this;`

```
function campaignProgress(goal, current) {
    this.goal = goal;
    this.current = current; 
    this.percent =  Math.floor(current / goal  * 100);

    var that = this;
    this.getGoal = function() {
        return that.goal;
    }
    this.getCurrent = function(){
        return that.current;
    }
    this.getPercent = function(){   
        return that.percent;
    }
}


var totalProgress = new campaignProgress(1.70, 1.064);
console.log(totalProgress.getGoal());
console.log(totalProgress.getPercent());
```

this always is the value inside a function(), if you where to call this.goal (as some mentioned above), that's the same as simply calling goal

Comment: @Teemu You don't **need** to use `that` here, but `this` isn't guaranteed to be what you expect in those methods. What if you did `var cp = new campaignProgress(1, 2), method = cp.getGoal; alert(method());`? This answer fixes that

Comment: @Teemu what i mean by closures here (maybe not correct term) is that ``this`` inside a function references what comes between the opening and closing bracket of that particular function.

Comment: @Teemu Ahh I see, I'm not sure if I missed that or what :)

Comment: Well, `return this.XXXX;` works only inside the constructor. I just realized what @Ian just has commented. When taken out of the context, we'll get `undefined`. Hence, it's always safest to set `var that = this` and use `that` in inner functions.

Answer (score 0):

Goal works because goal is defined within each function's closure (the goal argument that's passed into the function). The others don't work because they're not referenced with they keyword this (which is not nearly as optional as some languages). Unfortunately, due to the way this works, we can't simply add this to the return statement in each of the sub-functions (since we're not working on a prototype, the value of this could change depending on where we're calling these functions from). Thus, use the changes in bold.

```
function campaignProgress(goal, current){
    var self = this;
    this.goal = goal;
    this.current = current; 
    this.percent =  Math.floor(current / goal  * 100);

    this.getGoal = function(){
        return self.goal;
    }
    this.getCurrent = function(){
        return self.current;
    }
    this.getPercent = function(){   
        return self.percent;
    }
}
```

By using the self variable, we capture the value we want this to be when we first call the function, and then we operate on that.